# Multidimensional array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Would anyone be able to help out, im trying to think of a algorithm to find the number of dimensions and the size of the dimensions of a multidimensional array. 
However, not from  an array which is initialised like this : new int [2][2],
but an array which is initialised like this : {{}}.

Comment: if only arrays had some kind of length property....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because it's in fact an array of another array.

I hope the following explanation would be clear for you:

Having `int[][] array = new int[2][2] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};`. It means that there are two items containing an another array:

- array[0] contains the array {1, 2}
- array[1] contains the array {3, 4}

So together it gives you the 2D array. Please note that the size of each array is 2. No matters if the "inner" or the "outer" one.